# Is it possible to warp a Youtube Player Object (Flash/ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

I'd like to be able to warp a YouTube Player object in Flash around a sphere shape.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Youtube player or similar objects use StageVideo, this thing is in a separate layer than everything else, including Stage3D. You can try grabbing that video each frame and making a texture out of that to draw over that sphere, I expect it'll be very slow if at all possible.

Also, "wrap", not "warp".

Comment: One more question, related to this, is it possible to "wrap" a Video object (with a NetStream)? I know it can be distorted with `rotationX` and `rotationY`, but can it be envelope distorted with code?

Comment: @Kieran, same idea. NetStream is the underlying resource that handles the video streaming, however where it is drawn is still the question - that being StageVideo... or some other object via IBitmapDrawable

Comment: OK, thanks. Just started with ActionScript, so unsure of even the basics still!

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using the Youtube player you got a video URL you could try to use a [VideoTexture](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/) with [Away3D](http://away3d.com/). Truth be told, depending on the resolution of the video that will probably be a resource hog.

Here's a tutorial with a plane instead of a sphere, but it should be pretty similar.
http://www.ilike2flash.com/2012/11/videotexture-with-away3d-4.html

I've had more success with projecting video on 3d meshes using C++ frameworks like Cinder or OpenFrameworks.

Comment: Thanks, but is a bit advanced for my level of ActionScript at the moment. Upvoted anyway.